# Need to shake a collectionviewcell on didselectitematindexpath in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, cakeyframeanimation

[image]

```
CAKeyframeAnimation * anim = [ CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"] ;

anim.values = @[ [ NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) ], [ NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) ] ] ;
anim.autoreverses = YES;
anim.repeatCount = 2.0f;
anim.duration = 0.1f;

[cell.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil] ;
```

I write the above code to shake a collection view cell on selection. When i do it first time after viewing screen the frames of collection view cell get mismatched.While it works fine when i visit again to the view.
Please help me out why it is creating issue first time after add animation, if i remove animation then had no mismatch at first time as well but i require animation on touch.

While when i visit again again on this view and do section no frame get mismatched.Only have issue with first time selection on first visit on view.

Answer (score 2):

I got a solution of this issue why the frame of collection view cell get mismatched. It was causing due to a ToastView. I was showing an exceeded image message by toast. Now i use an alert view and it's working fine....

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for shake view.

```
#pragma mark
#pragma mark - ANIMATION SHAKE

- (void)shake:(UIView *)shakeView {

    CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    animation.duration = 0.6;
    animation.values = @[ @(-10), @(10), @(-10), @(10), @(-5), @(5), @(-2.5), @(5), @(0) ];
    [shakeView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"shake"];

}
```

Comment: The code provide by you also did the same thing.The code write by me in  question is working as per need but it has one issue. I am working on collectionView and i have to shake the particulate cell of collection on selection. Issue is that first time all frame get mismatched when i select on any cell while it work fine when i visit to view again and select on any cell.

Comment: @som can you put screen shot of that thing